# How to give label to synthetic data

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset

I am doing some research. I have created a dataset with 4 features using a uniform distribution.
I think it is a right way to do it but I am not sure.
I have done sum the features values/numbers of features, That's my actual probability for a sample. Then gave it to Bernollie distribution and get a class label. There is more randomness.

I have also tried, like if the actual probability > 0.50 then it labels 1 else 0. But there is no randomness.
I am wondering if there is another way to do it.

It would be also helpful if anybody can draw my attention to some literature or some Methods. I need to have the Probability of the sample so I can compare it with the output of ML framework.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. It's not really clear what you're trying to do, are you trying to simulate some specific kind of data? If you generate all the features and labels completely randomly with uniform distribution, there won't be any pattern in it and no model can learn it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am trying to simulate data. That's true there is no pattern, that's is I am not getting a proper result from the Model.
I do not know how to approach the problem. I have tried with e.g Uniform distribution but as you said there is no pattern.

Comment: let me explain to you, why I am creating simulated data. I have a ML framework, that gives me a specific label a probabilistic interval [low, high]. If I know before giving to model a sample, what probability that row has, to get label 1. I want to check if the actual probability is included in the Interval or not.

Comment: I think your problem is not defined clearly at this stage. I have two suggestions: 1) why not use some large real dataset? This would save you the trouble of generating artificial and it's considered much more solid if an algorithm is tested with real data. 2) do you know about sklearn [functions for generating artificial data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/sample_generators.html), in particular [make_classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html#sklearn.datasets.make_classification).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. With a real dataset, I do not know the actual probability or I do not know how to find it. I have also tried generating functions for data sets from sklearn but there is also the same problem. I want to know the probability of the sample.

let me give an Example.
Let's say I have a dataset, a sample (eg. index 10) from the dataset has a probability 0.80 that prediction would be class 1. I have trained my model with trainset and I gave a sample (index 10), model gives most probably me a predicted value 1 with probability interval.

Comment: I want to check if the given probability interval includes 0.80 or not. I hope that makes the question clear.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding about what the probability of a sample represents. Assuming a representative training set, if an instance (say index 10) has prob 0.8 of having class 1, it means that there are other instances with the same features in the training set (at some other indexes) and among all these instances 80% of them have label 1. This is actually the principle used by a decision tree algorithm, for example. So it's only a matter of finding a real dataset with duplicate (or near-duplicate) instances, so that the probability can be counted.